# Events in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

Below sample url is given

```
localhost/MyPage.aspx/1582%20
```

asp.net throw an error saying that this page does not exist and as far as I know it is because of the `%20` at the end of the URL.

the error is being caught by `Application_Error` in `Global.asax`, however I would like this to be redirected to a page and I would also like my `Application_Error` to log the errors, no page redirection

Are there other events in `Global.asax` that I can use to handle this redirection? I tried `PreSendRequestHeaders` but still it goes to `Application_Error`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't as there is [only one event for such situation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication_events.aspx) and it is `Application_Error` (event handlers in `Global.asax` are for `HttpApplication`).

But you can [implement an `IHttpModule`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms227673.aspx), parse the url in it, and if it is correct, redirect your user to target page (see also [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649096.aspx)).
You should remember that, by default, not all the requests are sent to the such modules, so you might have register your module in web.config by various way:

**Classic Mode**

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
<httpModules><add name="HelloWorldModule" type="HelloWorldModule"/></httpModules>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Integrated Mode**

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer><modules><add name="HelloWorldModule" type="HelloWorldModule"/></modules></system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[HTTP Handlers and HTTP Modules Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx)

Comment: @JanLyndonJasa https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx - see here a great overview